# What is the minimally-viable GUI for command-line Swift scripts?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I need a little helper GUI for my Swift script on macOS. It just needs a text entry field and an OK button.

I don't want to go the whole bloated Xcode route just for this little popup. However, Apple's documentation fails me because keyboard input isn't captured by my NSWindow. Help!

Comment: try event monitor https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534971-addlocalmonitorforeventsmatching

Comment: @MarekH Thanks, I looked into that and tried it, but then stumbled across the solution: `app.setActivationPolicy(.regular)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No thanks to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit), I finally figured out the magical incantations ‍♂️ needed to launch a simple AppKit/Cocoa GUI from a command-line Swift app *that accepts keyboard input*. **Without Xcode**!

This is also needed to accept text input in WKWebViews.

```
// main.swift // Dylan Sharhon // Tested on Catalina, Nov 2019
import AppKit // import Cocoa if you also need Foundation functionality

let app = NSApplication.shared
app.setActivationPolicy(.regular) // Magic to accept keyboard input and be docked!

let window = NSWindow.init(
  contentRect: NSRect(x: 300, y: 300, width: 200, height: 85),
  styleMask:   [
    NSWindow.StyleMask.titled     // Magic needed to accept keyboard input
  ],
  backing:     NSWindow.BackingStoreType.buffered,
  defer:       false
)
window.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)  // Magic needed to display the window

// Text input field
let text = NSTextField.init(string: "")
text.frame = NSRect(x: 10, y: 45, width: 180, height: 25)
window.contentView!.addSubview(text)

// Button
class Target {
  @objc func onClick () {         // Magic @objc needed for the button action
    print(text.stringValue)       // Goes to stdout
    exit(0)
  }
}
let target = Target()
let button = NSButton.init(
  title:  "OK",
  target: target,
  action: #selector(Target.onClick)
)
button.frame = NSRect(x:50, y:10, width:100, height:30)
window.contentView!.addSubview(button)

app.run()
```

To noobs like me: **This is the entire app** and you can run it with `swift main.swift` or compile it with `swiftc main.swift` and rename the resulting (merely 40 KB) executable to whatever you want to be in the menubar.

Comment: If you add `#!/usr/bin/swift` at the beginning you can run it as a script too.

Comment: You need `app.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)` just before app.run to make app window show on top of all other apps.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a little script which is able to show a window in swift. The goal was to show the output of several shell commands (`brew update` & `brew upgrade` & `brew cleanup` & `brew doctor`). These commands can take significant amount of time if you do not perform them everyday and I was tired of having to wait sometime 10 minutes just for the 2 first commands to complete.

I could have simply launched a cron job or used launchd with a shell script, but I wanted to be able to check the success or failure of the commands, especially the `brew doctor`, to know if I needed to perform some action to clean my homebrew install on my machine.

So I needed a window to show up with the error and standard output of the commands and more, I wanted to produce a binary of it.

After searching a bit on Google and Github, I found swift-sh, which allow to import Github repository (in a standardized way through Swift Package Manager) and use it in a swift script and compile it if needed ; and ShellOut, by the same guy, which allows to perform shell commands from a swift script and collects the output of the command in an swift object.

Basically, it should have been a little window with a textview in a scrollview, which showed the output of the shell commands while being able to scroll it.

Here the Script :

```
#!/usr/bin/swift sh


import AppKit
import Foundation
// importing ShellOut from GitHub repository
// The magic of swift-sh happens
import ShellOut // @JohnSundell

// Declare the Application context
let app = NSApplication.shared

// Create the delegate class responsible for the window and crontrol creation
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var str: String? = ""

    // Construct the window
    let theWindow = NSWindow(contentRect: NSMakeRect(200, 200, 400, 200),
                          styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable],
                          backing: .buffered,
                          defer: false,
                          screen: nil)

    var output: String? = ""

    // What happens once application context launched
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {

        var str = ""

        // The shell commands and the collect of output
        do {
            str =  try shellOut(to: "brew", arguments: ["update"] )
            output = output! + str
        } catch {
            let error1 = error as! ShellOutError
            //print(error1.message)
            output = output! + error1.message
        }

        do {
            str = try shellOut(to: "brew", arguments: ["upgrade"] )
            output = output! + "\n" + str
            //print("step 2")
        } catch {
            let error2 = error as! ShellOutError
            //print(error2.message)
            output = output! + "\n" + error2.message
        }

        do {
            str = try shellOut(to: "brew", arguments: ["cleanup"] )
            output = output! + "\n" + str
            //print("step 3")
        } catch {
            let error3 = error as! ShellOutError
            //print(error3.message)
            output = output! + "\n" + error3.message
        }

        do {
            str = try shellOut(to: "brew", arguments: ["doctor"] )
            output = output! + "\n" + str
             //print("step 4")
        } catch {
            let error4 = error as! ShellOutError
            //print(error4.message)
            output = output! + "\n" + error4.message
        }

        // Controls placement and content goes here
        // ScrollView...
        var theScrollview = NSScrollView(frame: theWindow.contentView!.bounds)
        var contentSize = theScrollview.contentSize
        theScrollview.borderType = .noBorder
        theScrollview.hasVerticalScroller = true
        theScrollview.hasHorizontalScroller = false
        theScrollview.autoresizingMask = NSView.AutoresizingMask(rawValue: NSView.AutoresizingMask.width.rawValue | NSView.AutoresizingMask.height.rawValue | NSView.AutoresizingMask.minYMargin.rawValue | NSView.AutoresizingMask.minYMargin.rawValue)

        // TextView...
        var theTextView = NSTextView(frame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, contentSize.width, contentSize.height))
        theTextView.minSize = NSMakeSize(0.0, contentSize.height)
        theTextView.maxSize = NSMakeSize(CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        theTextView.isVerticallyResizable = true
        theTextView.isHorizontallyResizable = false
        theTextView.autoresizingMask = NSView.AutoresizingMask(rawValue: NSView.AutoresizingMask.width.rawValue | NSView.AutoresizingMask.height.rawValue | NSView.AutoresizingMask.minYMargin.rawValue | NSView.AutoresizingMask.minYMargin.rawValue)
        theTextView.textContainer?.containerSize = NSMakeSize(contentSize.width, CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        theTextView.backgroundColor = .white
        theTextView.textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = true
        theTextView.textStorage?.append(NSAttributedString(string: output!))

        theScrollview.documentView = theTextView

        theWindow.contentView = theScrollview
        theWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
        theWindow.makeFirstResponder(theTextView)
    }

    // What happens when we click the close button of the window
    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
      return true;
    }
}

// Instantiation of the application delegate class
// and launching
let delegate = AppDelegate()
    app.delegate = delegate
    app.run()
```